# notifyDataSetChanged() vs. notifyItemChanged() for varying datasize

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a simple `RecyclerView` with a dataset of up to 5000 items.

The user can select items and update their data with a simple button click.

**The problem**:

- If the user selects only a few items, calling `notifyItemChanged()` on each item seems more efficient than calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`.
- On the other hand, if the user selects let's say 4000 items out of 5000, calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` if far more efficient (according to my benchmarks) than calling `notifyItemChanged()` on each item.

(`notifyItemRangeChanged()` is out of the question, the selection may not be continous at all)

Can i optimize my code for this somehow? Obviously i cannot know how many items the user will select. Is there a common practice for this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i wonder how quickly the user will be able to select a row, in normal cases item changed would be better.

Comment: @SarthakMittal it doesn't matter how quick the select is, the update is the important operation and it's a single button click. Something like `updateSelectedItems(selectedItems)`. And that's when the notify method is called. `selectedItems` can be 3 but also 3000 items, that's the problematic part.

Answer (score 0):

I think for optimization point of view you can use `notifiyItemChanged(int location)` would help to notify on the specified/selected position only. This is the much better than to call notifiyItemChanged(). Becuase as you know it would inform all of the items.